# Multiple Plots Using ggplot for time series data

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I have data for damage and TD for two genotypes for 2, 4, 6 and 8 weeks. I want to see correlation (scatterplot) for each week between "damage" and "TD".

Could you please let me know how I can do that and create 4x4 scatter plot for each week?

```
Genotype    Week    Damage     TD
       M       2       85     120
       M       2      358   119.5
       M       2      446    72.5
       M       2      255    67.5
       L       2       50   109.5
       L       2       24      68
       L       2       25   146.5
       L       2        0      89
       .       .        .       .
       .       .        .       .
       .       .        .       .
       .       .        .       .
       .       .        .       .
       .       .        .       .
       .       .        .       .
       M       8     1068     207
       M       8     2605     228
       M       8     1623   226.5
       M       8     1284   316.5
       L       8      393   163.5
       L       8      957      68
       L       8      268      85
       L       8      446   208.5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Damage, y = TD)) + geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~Week)
```

[image]

Comment: That did work, I wanted to make correlation and then put correlation values on same plots. somehow i,m not able to do. could you pls suggest something.

gplot(data, aes(x = TD, y = damage)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  facet_grid(~Leafstage1)



# Calculate correlation for each group
library(plyr)
cors <- ddply(data, .(TD, Silverdamage), summarise, cor = round(cor(TD, damage), 2))
p + geom_text(data=cors, aes(label=paste("r=", cor, sep="")), x=0.5, y=0.5)